# Core-Plot: How to add button on CPLayerHostingView

Tags: objective-c, iphone, graph, core-plot

I would like to add some buttons on CPLayerHostingView. I have tried the same by creating some an object of UIButton and adding it as subview on my CPLayerHostingView but it didn't worked as expected. Please help me to do the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're better off not adding subviews into a CPLayerHostingView. Add the buttons to the CPLayerHostingView's superview instead.

Answer (score 2):

Nice to know that the answer given by Eric Skroch is worked for sandy. 
But I am just trying here to help other people who have the same question and when come here, found no code examples. (Because I had the same experience)

You can find the [example code here](http://groups.google.com/group/coreplot-discuss/browse_thread/thread/6cd652527f9ae6e2/47fd7988d84067cf?lnk=gst&q=button#). (open the link and read the post of 'Ivan Rambius Ivanov' )